# Gnuplot: Why is the first line automatically ignored in my datafile

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a .csv datafile that should be plotted using `gnuplot`.
Let's assume the file has the following format:

```
A;B;C;D;E;F
1;1;2;1;1;1
2;3;3;3;5;6
3;4;1;1;1;4
```

The first column (column A) is the x-axis, column B to F each should be plotted as own lineplot (yes, I know, too many line plots within one plot may look bad, but just to get an idea). Here a MCVE:

```
set terminal png size 1000,500    
set datafile separator ";" # CSV file is seperated with ;
plot \
  'C://tmp/test.csv' using 1:2 with lines title "B",\
  'C://tmp/test.csv' using 1:3 with lines title "C",\
  'C://tmp/test.csv' using 1:4 with lines title "D",\
  'C://tmp/test.csv' using 1:5 with lines title "E",\
  'C://tmp/test.csv' using 1:6 with lines title "F"
```

I read that to ignore the first line in the datafile I would have to comment it, starting the line with `#`, like `#A;B;C;D;E;F`; or to use `plot <filename> every ::1` to ignore the first line, which would mean that I would have to include `every ::1` 5 times in the above script, as explained [in this link](http://jchain.github.io/blog/2011/11/08/gnuplot-how-to-skip-the-first-line-in-the-data-file/).

Nevertheless, above script just runs fine and creates a valid .png, automatically ignoring the first line in the .csv.

I know "*Why bothering if it works anyway*"? But I always want to know what's going on, so: Why does this happen? Has something changed within gnuplot so that it detects header lines automatically and it is not needed anymore to comment the header line in a .csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that gnuplot recognizes the first line as being headers or labels, it's just that it gets no valid point to plot from the first line.  Where would you plot the point (A,B)?  It has no value.  (2,3) is a point you can plot, but not (A,B).  Since it's not a valid point, it just ignores it.

Try removing all other lines of the input file, so that it reads only

```
A;B;C;D;E;F
```

It will give a warning that it is "Skipping data file with no valid points".

The comment (line starting with `#`) is useful to explicitly ignore the line instead of just hoping that it isn't interpreted as a plottable value.  What if the line with your column headers had numbers in it?  It might try to plot it, which isn't what you would want.

Ignoring unplottable data points can be useful.  You can filter out values that you don't want plotted by having them evaluate to `NaN` (not a number).  Since it can't plot `NaN`, it ignores it.  For example:

```
plot 'C://tmp/test.csv' using ($1<10 ? NaN : $1):2 with lines title "B"
```

will only plot only those points where the *x* value is least 10, ignoring all others because they evaluate to `NaN`, which is unplottable.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. I didn't know that unplotable values are ignored automatically, I thought an error would be printed if some invalid data is read. I just did some tests with unplotable values within the .csv (eg. replacing some number with a letter) and everything is just as you explained.

Comment: Conditionally ignoring them on purpose (such as with `NaN`) is very useful, and a common technique.  It gives no error on an invalid value, just a warning if it ignored _all_ the lines in a file (or found none).  So if you do ignore things on purpose like this, pay attention to gnuplot's stderr output.